# Material UI + Tailwind put image right of text

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

*Just use "float-right"*. Of course, it's a bit more complicated than that.
I have the follwing code in my react project:

```js
<div style={{marginLeft: 20,wordWrap: "break-word",width: 350}}>
  <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor.</h1>
  <img className="float-right" alt="test" src="https://dummyimage.com/100"/>
</div>
```

I want the image to be on the right side of the text, but right now, it just looks like this:

[image: ![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSGo9.png)]
But I want the 100x100 image on the right side of the text, how would I go about this?
And doing it like this also doesn't work:

```js
<div style={{marginLeft: 20,wordWrap: "break-word",width: 350}}>
  <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Find out what were working on and more in our blog</h1>
</div>
<img className="float-right" alt="test" src="https://dummyimage.com/100"/>
```

[image]

I'm really bad at CSS...

Comment: Just use `display: flex` on `div` tag (flex-flow: row) will do the work for you

Comment: @Rana that works but its squishing the image https://i.imgur.com/Uk4wjSu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` to have image and text side by side . This is possible as default `flex-flow` value is `row` .

If wanted to prevent shrinking of image or anything in `flex` use `flex-shrink: 0;` but this works when you define the `width` `height` values

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="marginLeft: 20,wordWrap: " break-word ",width: 350">
  <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor.</h1>
  <img alt="test" src="https://dummyimage.com/100" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I do it the opposite way (Image *left* of text)

Comment: Put image tag before the `h1` element to have image on the left